# Protobuf to json in python

Tags: python, json, protocol-buffers

I have an object that I de-serialize using `protobuf` in Python. When I print the object it looks like a python object, however when I try to convert it to `json` I have all sorts of problems.

For example, if I use `json.dumps()` I get that the object (the generated code from protoc) does not contain a _ *dict* _ error.

If I use jsonpickle I get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 97: invalid start byte`.

Test code below is using `jsonpickle` with the error shown above.

```
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print ("Error: missing ser file")
    sys.exit()
else :
    fileLocation = sys.argv[1]

org = BuildOrgObject(fileLocation) 

org = org.Deserialize()


#print (org)
jsonObj = jsonpickle.encode(org)
print (jsonObj)
```

Comment: This would be way easier to figure out if you showed us the relevant parts of your .proto file and the implementation of BuildOrgObject().  If we can reproduce the behavior you're seeing, it's much easier for us to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 235):

I'd recommend using protobuf↔json converters from google's [protobuf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/protobuf) library:

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson

json_obj = MessageToJson(org)
```

You can also serialise the protobuf to a dictionary:

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict
dict_obj = MessageToDict(org)
```

Refer to the protobuf package API documentation: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/ (see module `google.protobuf.json_format`).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be available in version `3.2`?

Comment: I've done a quick test (clean venv, install protobuf, try to import MessageToJson) and it seems to be available. Python 3.6.

Comment: google.protobuf.json_format comes to be supported since proto2.7.

Comment: 2.7? I only know of 2.6.1 to be the latest release https://pypi.python.org/pypi/protobuf

Comment: The bytes field converts to base64 string with this, anyway to go around that?

Comment: `MessageToJson(org, preserving_proto_field_name=True)` if you don't want your `field_name` converted into `fieldName`

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I get the error: AttributeError: 'Schema' object has no attribute 'DESCRIPTOR'

Comment: same for me @Alex 
have u found the solution ?

Comment: @Alex did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope:-( unfortunately I am not anymore on it.

Comment: @RobinNemeth, `fieldName` *should* be converted to `field_name` when converting to JSON with Protobuf 3. The spec defines a strict mapping between Protobuf 3 messages and JSON. It's part of the spec!

Comment: If you are running this on a repeated sub field (instead of on a regular message) then it will fail with missing DESCRIPTOR. Use the main message, or convert to dict each of the elements and combine

Comment: I have the same error AttributeError: 'DESCRIPTOR', someone fixed the error?

Comment: Have you tried `BuildOrgObject.to_json(org)`? See https://github.com/googleapis/python-vision/issues/64#issuecomment-712617747

Comment: Does anyone know why MessageToDict converts fixed64 fields in protobuf message to strings in the Dict ? Is there a way to override this behavior ? For me this conversion is posing problems in using this API

Comment: Works for me. Make sure you encode the data before sending.
        json_obj = MessageToJson(al)
        data = json_obj
        data = data.encode("utf-8")

Comment: `json_obj` is of type `str` so i think name as `json_str` is less misleading.

Comment: I got it working with the following approaches:
1) `json_string = type(response).to_json(response)`
2) ```import proto
json_string = proto.Message.to_json(response)```
3) `MessageToJson(response._pb)`
Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64403737/attribute-error-descriptor-while-trying-to-convert-google-vision-response-to-dic

Answer (score 17):

If you need to go straight to json take a look at the [protobuf-to-json](https://github.com/dpp-name/protobuf-json) library, but you'll have to install that manually.

But I would recommend that you use the [protobuf-to-dict](https://github.com/benhodgson/protobuf-to-dict) library instead for a few reasons:

1. It is accessible from pypi so you can simply `pip install protobuf-to-dict` or include it in a `requirements.txt`
2. `dict` can be converted to json and might be more useful than a json string

Comment: `protobuf-to-dict` feels more pythonic than `google.protobuf.json_format`

Comment: There is now a method include with protobuf for converting to a dict instead of json. It is called: `google.protobuf.json_format.MessageToDict`

Comment: Requires implementing MyMessage to get things going.  Kind of incomplete since thats a big part of parsing a proto?

Comment: That's a limitation of protobuf itself. Unlike something like json, a protobuf message cannot describe itself, and a schema must be created in order to either encode or decode a message. Without a schema, it is just a byte blob without enough information to parse.

Comment: I tried using protobuf_to_dict on python 3 and got this error: `File ...protobuf_to_dict.py", line 15, in <module>
    FieldDescriptor.TYPE_INT64: long,`
I assume this means it only works for python 2.7?

Comment: @Stian - try the updated version: pip install protobuf3-to-dict

Answer (score 3):

Here's my function to convert a proto3 object to a JSON object (i.e. Python dictionary):

```
def protobuf_to_dict(proto_obj):
    key_list = proto_obj.DESCRIPTOR.fields_by_name.keys()
    d = {}
    for key in key_list:
        d[key] = getattr(proto_obj, key)
    return d
```

Since the converters from Google's protobuf library don't seem to work in some cases with the 3.19 version, this function leverages the [Descriptor class present on each Protobuf object](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/descriptor.html).

Here, `getattr(obj, string_attribute)` returns the value given by `obj.attribute`

Answer (score 2):

You can also user SerializeToString.

```
org.SerializeToString()
```

Comment: This does not return the JSON representation of the Protobuf message. It returns the Protobuf-encoded serialized messages as bytes (see [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial#parsing-and-serialization)).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an older version that doesn't has the **preserving_proto_field_name** field:

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson
def proto_to_json(proto_obj):
    json_obj = MessageToJson(proto_obj):
    json_obj = MessageToJso, including_default_value_fields=True)
    # Change lowerCamelCase of google Json conversion to the snake_case as in original protobuf
    dict_obj = dict((re.sub(r'(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])', '_', k).lower(),v) for k, v in json.loads(json_obj).items())
    if hasattr(proto_obj, 'uuid'):
        dict_obj["uuid"] = proto_obj.uuid.encode("hex")
    return json.dumps(dict_obj, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```