# Convert Google Vision API response to JSON

Tags: python, json, google-api

**Task**:

- Convert Google Vision API response to JSON

**Problem**:

- The return value from the API call is not in a JSON format

**Python Function**

```
def detect_logos(path):
"""Detects logos in the file."""
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

# [START migration_logo_detection]
with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = types.Image(content=content)

response = client.logo_detection(image=image)
logos = response.logo_annotations

print('Logos:')
print(logos)
print(type(logos))
```

**Google online JSON**

```
"logoAnnotations": [
{
  "mid": "/m/02wwnh",
  "description": "Maxwell House",
  "score": 0.41142157,
  "boundingPoly": {
    "vertices": [
      {
        "x": 74,
        "y": 129
      },
      {
        "x": 161,
        "y": 129
      },
      {
        "x": 161,
        "y": 180
      },
      {
        "x": 74,
        "y": 180
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Google Response (List)**

```
 [mid: "/m/02wwnh"
description: "Maxwell House"
score: 0.4114215672016144
bounding_poly {
  vertices {
    x: 74
    y: 129
  }
  vertices {
    x: 161
    y: 129
  }
  vertices {
    x: 161
    y: 180
  }
  vertices {
    x: 74
    y: 180
  }
}
]
```

**Type**:

> google.protobuf.internal.containers.RepeatedCompositeFieldContainer

**Tried**:

[Protobuf to json in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734617/protobuf-to-json-in-python)

Comment: Do you have the python script you wrote returning just Google Response (List), is it returned without commas or simply the way you have it here ?

Comment: yes it is without commas, exactly what i have pasted

Comment: can you provide a simplified version of the call in a small python script... i will run it and get to the bottom of the problem

Comment: sure, please check it. that function calls vision API and I get response which I mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found solution. It can not be converted to JSON but can be accessed like this:

```
print(logos[0].bounding_poly.vertices[0].x)
```

Comment: Thank you @Kushal for clearing my doubt. I was facing many difficulties in using Vision API. This worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

Google vision 2.0 requires different code and will throw the following error if the code isn't changed:

```
object has no attribute 'DESCRIPTOR'
```

Here is an example of how to serialize and de-serialize using json and/or protobuf:

```
import io, json
from google.cloud import vision_v1
from google.cloud.vision_v1 import AnnotateImageResponse

with io.open('000048.jpg', 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = vision_v1.Image(content=content)
client = vision_v1.ImageAnnotatorClient()
response = client.document_text_detection(image=image)

# serialize / deserialize proto (binary)
serialized_proto_plus = AnnotateImageResponse.serialize(response)
response = AnnotateImageResponse.deserialize(serialized_proto_plus)
print(response.full_text_annotation.text)

# serialize / deserialize json
response_json = AnnotateImageResponse.to_json(response)
response = json.loads(response_json)
print(response['fullTextAnnotation']['text'])
```

*Note 1*: proto-plus doesn't support converting to snake_case names, which is supported in protobuf with "preserving_proto_field_name=True". So currently there is no way around the field names being converted from response['full_text_annotation'] to response['fullTextAnnotation']
There is an open feature request for this: googleapis/proto-plus-python#109

*Note 2*: The google vision api doesn't return an x coordinate if x=0. If x doesn't exist, the protobuf will default x=0. In python vision 1.0.0 using MessageToJson(), these x values weren't included in the json, but now with python vision 2.0.0 and .To_Json() these values are included as x:0

Comment: This also fixed the Japanese language encoding issues I had!

Answer (score 8):

That library returns plain protobuf objects, which can be serialized to JSON using:

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson
serialized = MessageToJson(original)
```

This worked for me.

Comment: it returns this error: `AttributeError: 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedCompositeCo' object has no attribute 'DESCRIPTOR'`

Comment: `MessageToJson(response._pb)` worked for me. [credit to Martin J](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64403737/attribute-error-descriptor-while-trying-to-convert-google-vision-response-to-dic)