# Migrating data from Datastore to Bigquery with Dataflow

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to write a dataflow pipeline to migrate data from google Datastore to BigQuery using Python. After some search I figured I need to do three steps:

```
    1. ReadFromDatastore
    2. Convert to Python dicts or Tablerows
    3. WriteToBigQuery
```

Now, first and last step is simple as they are the functions themselves. But I am having hard time in finding a good way to do the second step.

I wrote the output of ReadFromDatastore to a text file and json looks like as below:

```
key {
  partition_id {
    project_id: "ProjectID"
  }
  path {
    kind: "KindName"
    id:9999
  }
}
properties {
  key: "property1"
  value {
    string_value: "property_value"
  }
}
properties {
  key: "property2"
  value {
    string_value: ""
  }
}
properties {
  key: "property3"
  value {
    boolean_value: false
  }
}
properties {
  key: "created"
  value {
    timestamp_value {
      seconds: 4444
      nanos: 2222
    }
  }
}
properties {
  key: "created_by"
  value {
    string_value: "property_value"
  }
}
properties {
  key: "date_created"
  value {
    timestamp_value {
      seconds: 4444
    }
  }
}
properties {
  key: "property4"
  value {
    string_value: "property_value"
  }
}
properties {
  key: "property5"
  value {
    array_value {
      values {
        meaning: 00
        string_value: "link"
        exclude_from_indexes: true
      }
    }
  }
}
properties {
  key: "property6"
  value {
    null_value: NULL_VALUE
  }
}
properties {
  key: "property7"
  value {
    string_value: "property_value"
  }
}
properties {
  key: "property8"
  value {
    string_value: ""
  }
}
properties {
  key: "property9"
  value {
    timestamp_value {
      seconds: 3333
      nanos: 3333
    }
  }
}
properties {
  key: "property10"
  value {
    meaning: 00
    string_value: ""
    exclude_from_indexes: true
  }
}
properties {
  key: "property11"
  value {
    boolean_value: false
  }
}
properties {
  key: "property12"
  value {
    array_value {
      values {
        key_value {
          partition_id {
            project_id: "project_id"
          }
          path {
            kind: "Another_kind_name"
            id: 4444
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
properties {
  key: "property13"
  value {
    string_value: "property_value"
  }
}
properties {
  key: "version"
  value {
    integer_value: 4444
  }
}

key {
  partition_id {
    project_id: "ProjectID"
  }
  path {
    kind: "KindName"
    id: 9999
  }
}
.
.
.
.next_entity/row
```

Do I have to write a custom function to convert json to python dicts to be able to write to BigQuery or are there any functions/libraries from google datastore or apache that I can use?

I found an [article](https://blog.papercut.com/google-cloud-dataflow-data-migration/) describing what I am trying to do but code shown is in Java.

Comment: I do not think this is JSON. This may be a protobuf-style object. Can you check (by logging the type of the objects)? - if so, you can convert the protobufs into JSON by following these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734617/protobuf-to-json-in-python

Answer (score 1):

The output of the `ReadFromDatastore` transform is of `Entity`-typed protocol buffers.

To convert protobuff to JSON, you can check this question: [Protobuf to json in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734617/protobuf-to-json-in-python)

You would do:

```
p | ReadFromDatastore(...) | beam.Map(my_proto_to_json_fn) | beam.WriteToBigQuery(...)
```

Comment: I am not able to run "my_proto_to_json_fn" but logged the type of element, it's coming out to be 'unicode'. My code is:
`objects = (p | 'Read from Text' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(input_file)) 
 objects | 'Convert to Dict' >> beam.Pardo(Protobuf2Dict())
 objects | 'Debug print' >> beam.ParDo(PrintFn())`
And PrintFn is:
`class PrintFn(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    print (type(element))
    print (element)
    return None`

Comment: okay... so now you can take those unicode elements and make them json maybe?